# Suppose buses arrive at the bus stop every 30 min on average

Tags: probability

there are two questions.

(a) If there the interarrival time is a constant, what would be the expected waiting time for a randomly arriving passenger?

(b) What if the interarrival time is random? Is the waiting time shorter than, same as, or longer than your answer to part (a)?

Some one help me to approach this problem mathematically?

Answer (score 3):

If the interarrival time is a constant $30$ minutes, the expected waiting time for a uniformly randomly arriving passenger is $15$ minutes.

If the arrivals form a Poisson process with rate $\lambda=(30\,\text{min})^{-1}$, the expected waiting time for a uniformly randomly arriving passenger is

$$
\lambda\int_0^\infty t\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}\,\mathrm dt=\frac1\lambda=30\,\text{min}\;.
$$

The expected waiting time is longer because the uniformly randomly arriving passenger is more likely to arrive during one of the longer intervals than during one of the shorter intervals. To see this effect without the complications of randomness, imagine two buses arriving in close succession every hour. Then the average arrival rate is again one per $30\,\text{min}$ and the average waiting time is roughly $30\,\text{min}$, as in the random case. Here, too, the irregular interarrival times lead to the passengers tending to arrive in the longer intervals and thus having to wait longer on average.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have two more Qs. 
1) I cannot figure out why the expected waiting time is 15 mins if the interarrival time is a constant 30 mins. I think If we let Y as the actual time of arrival of a bus, then Y forms a uniform distribution over the interval of (0,30). Then, E(Y) = 0+30/2 = 15 by a formulation. But, E[Y] = E[waiting time]? can you show me how these two parameters are related to each other.

Comment: @Kennywong: If the buses arrive in regular intervals, their arrival times are not random variables. The only randomness in this case is from the uniformly randomly arriving passengers. A passenger arrives during any one of the $30\,\text{min}$ intervals and is equally likely to arrive at any time during this interval.

Comment: Okay, If I let Y as 'the actual time of arrival of a passenger after the last bus departed' (0<y<30), then I can let (30-Y) as the waiting time for a uniformly randomly arriving passenger. Then, expected waiting time, E[30-Y] = -E(Y)+30 = -15+30 = 15. Am I doing right?

Comment: @Kennywong: Yes -- just a bit unnecessarily complicated, since 'the actual time of arrival of a passenger after the last bus departed' and 'the actual time of arrival of a passenger before the next bus will depart' have the same (uniform) distribution, so you don't really need all this subtraction.

Comment: I got what you are pointing out, but... I am stuck in catching the relationship btw 'the actual time of arrival of a passenger' and 'the waiting time for the passenger'. Please explain it in great detail if you can.

Comment: @Kennywong: 'the actual time of arrival of a passenger before the next bus will depart' is the same thing as 'the waiting time for the passenger'. The passenger will wait until the next bus departs.

Comment: I got it perfectly now. Thanks for your brilliant comments along my Qs!