# The expected waiting time for a bus that comes each c minutes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

This is not exactly a homework questions, but it's going to help me in solving another homework question (i,e.  hints are great also ):

What's the expected waiting time for a passenger for a bus which arrived each $c$ minutes? The passenger will arrive at any time and assume the bus is operating 24/7.

Comment: What do you mean by hitting or missing a bus?  From Piet Hein: "you'll always be late for the previous train and always in time for the next."

Comment: @RossMillikan catching a bus

Comment: Please see the edited comment.  I got a return I didn't mean so it posted early.  A more reasonable question is what is the expected time to wait for a bus.

Comment: @RossMillikan well, this is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @cyberic Your question makes no more sense for 'catching' than 'hitting' (though 'catching' is the better word). You cannot solve a problem (and we cannot help you) unless it is well-posed. What would it mean for an observer to 'catch the bus'?

Comment: You haven't defined a clear problem.  You will always miss a bus and always catch one.

Comment: @RossMillikan You are right, my problem was ill-posed. I make an edit hopefully it becomes a well-posed now (I just figured out I wasn't thinking properly about this problem)

Comment: Okay (re your edit) say I arrive at 5:15 and the previous bus came at 5:05 and the next bus arrives at 5:30. Did I catch or miss the bus?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm asking about the expected waiting time now. Based on your example, the waiting time is 15 minutes.

Comment: @cyberic That is a well-posed question.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah, you re-adjust my way of thinking in a proper way :)

Comment: What do you mean by "constant rate"? That the time between two adjacent busses is constant? That the probability of a bus arriving in any given minute is constant? Something else entirely? (See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394808/suppose-buses-arrive-at-the-bus-stop-every-30-min-on-average?rq=1) for an example of why this matters — just specifying the average rate that busses arrive at is not enough to get the expected wait time for a passenger...)

Comment: @cyberic:  one big thing in math (and elsewhere) is thinking about your question to make sure it has a good answer.  Once you do that many questions become easy.  The others become research papers.

Comment: @Micah I mean that each, for instance, 10 minutes a bus arrive.

Comment: @RossMillikan haha I will print your quote and hang it on my desk.

Comment: The whole grook is [here](https://allpoetry.com/Thoughts-on-a-Station-Platform)

Comment: @RossMillikan "You'll always be late 
for the previous train, 
and always on time 
for the next." I'm going to write this down on my answer sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have specified that the buses arrive regularly and (have sort of specified that) the passengers arrive randomly, the average waiting time is $\frac c2$ minutes.  You can just focus on the interval before the next bus and it becomes clear.  This is exactly what I meant with the comment that you need to ask a question that has a clear answer.

Comment: How did you calculate the average waiting time?

Comment: Formally, if $p(t)dt$ is the probability of waiting between $t$ and $t+dt$ the average waiting time is $\int_0^ctp(t)dt$ and $p(t)=\frac 1c$.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This answer refers to the original version of OP's question.

I think there are a few information missing in this post. But the format of the question is way to familiar not to answer. It is basic queuing theory. I'll try.

The rate of arrival $c>0$ alludes to a Poisson distribution which makes sense in the context of arrivals, as it implies the exponentially distributed interarrival times which follow the Markov property.

**Simple approach**: Assume you are standing at the bus stop for a fixed, i.e. known unit of time. Assuming further that the random variable $N$ specifies the number of buses arriving with a rate of $c>0$ (the rate is specified in exactly the same unit of time) is Poisson-distributed, i.e. $N \sim Poi(c)$.
Then, the probability of you 'catching' **a** bus (as several buses can arrive) is
$$ \mathbb{P}(\mbox{'Catching a bus'}) =  \mathbb{P}(N \geq 1) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(N=k) = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c^{k}}{k!}e^{-c} = 1 - \frac{c^{0}}{0!} e^{-c} = 1 - e^{-c} \mbox{.}$$

In short, it is just the complementary event of no bus arriving during that time interval.

EDIT: This yields an expected waiting time of $\frac{1}{c}$ since interarrival times are exponentially distributed with the rate as mentioned before.

**More elaborated approach**:
What is missing is definitely the (possibly probabilistic) nature of your arrival and the (possibly probabilistic) duration the bus actually stops for you to 'catch' it. This is way more complicated as we have to specify a joint probability measure on the 3 components. This would still neglect real life restrictions such as limitations on the number of buses able to stop at the same time etc.

Comment: I don't think this is the question the OP is trying to ask.  I think he means, after the person arrives at the bus stop, what is the average time he waits until the next bus comes?  So, with you approach, I think you need to say that Poisson arrivals have exponential inter-arrival times, etc.  Of course, I could be wrong; the question is not at all well-posed.

Comment: Right, I added the expected value. I mentioned the exponential distribution of arrival times in the 2nd paragraph. I did not wanted to go into too much detail about the rationale behind the exponential distribution & it's Markov property as it dilutes the answer further.

Comment: Yes, especially since we don't even know for sure that the OP is talking about Poisson arrivals.

Comment: Please see the edit in my question, I misused the concept of constant rate. I meant that the bus arrives each $c$ minutes

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of text obsolete in my post.